# Space divs vertically on post feed, Tumblr

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with [this theme](http://vanity-theme.tumblr.com/#/twitter).

I can't seem to get the divs to separate and view the background properly.
I've played with margin-bottom but the divs get the BG from the .panel, I'd also like to make the border-radius carry through.

Do I need to add color to #twitter-info and #tweets and just mess with each element?
I've read to make it into a table?

Seems like an easy task but I'm just butchering this!

[Current](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k3r1cvn5x5r3y47/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-31%20at%202.59.03%20PM.png)

[image: Current]

[Want](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8u8iizcckyypsq/Spaced_Divs.png)

[image: Want]

Thank you in advance, or if I need to clarify anything. The second image should explain it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy to do that. Firstly change this:

```
#twitter #tweets .tweet {
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 28px;
padding: 60px 70px 20px;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(237, 237, 237);
}
```

to this

```
#twitter #tweets .tweet {
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 28px;
padding: 60px 70px 20px;
margin: 20px 0;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

... and then remove the background color on `.panel`.

Comment: Great! Thank you Ralph, I had a drop shadow on .panel so in my eyes it looked visible at a glance.Then of course I took the ax to it with z-index and everything else I could think of. Have to remember to keep it simple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

## **White Background Problem**

There is nothing wrong with what you're doing, the only reason it "**seems**" like the margin-bottom isn't working is because the "**panel**" class is underneath the "**tweet**" class.

The **panel** class has a background of white. If you remove this background color. You'll get your desired results.